# MATLAB C matrix interface: does mxDestroyArray recursively destroy elements of cells and structs?

Tags: c, matlab, mex, matlab-engine

The question is in the title: does `mxDestroyArray()` recursively destroy *elements* of cells and structs? Is is about MATLAB's [C matrix library interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cc-mx-matrix-library.html).

To explain in more detail through a concrete example, suppose that I create a 1 by 1 cell using `mxCreateCellArray()`, then create a numeric matrix using `mxCreateNumericArray()` and set it as the only element of the cell. Now will calling `mxDestroyArray()` on the cell destroy the numeric array as well, in one go?  Or do I need to call it separately for the numerical array, then the cell?  I am hoping for the latter, as this is more reasonable for complex manipulations.

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxdestroyarray.html) is ambiguous on this point.  Also, it's not easy to devise a test that would give a definitive answer to this.

Comment: Cross posted here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63726-does-mxdestroyarray-recursively-de-allocate-elements-of-structs-and-cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to the reply I got on MATLAB answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63726#answer_75323), `mxDestroyArray()` does free elements of cells and structs recursively.   Please see that answer for an example program that confirms this.